# Fetch txt file working on local but not when hosted on github with certain txt files

Tags: javascript, github, fetch, github-pages

I have hosted my project on github found here and have a function where it fetches txt files and puts it into an assigned div.

The txt files are all located in the project file on github.

The function works with only one text file but on the others I get an error message

Unfortunately I don't know how to resolve this but i feel the issue is with the txt files due to the function working fine with one of the txt files but not the two others.

I've tried changing the capitals just incase its case sensitive.

This is the function to fetch

```js
function getText() {
  const books = document.getElementsByClassName('book_selection')
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    books[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML
      fetch(e.target.innerHTML.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "")+".txt")
      .then(function(response){
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function(myBook) {
        let text = myBook;
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = text;
      })
      .then(function(){
        $(".word_split").lettering('words');
        getTranslation()
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This is the error message

"The Content Security Policy 'default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data:; connect-src 'self'' was delivered via a  element outside the document's , which is disallowed. The policy has been ignored."

What should be happening is retrieving the txt file and putting it into the specified div.

Comment: Is protocol set in the urls within the html, or are they relative urls?

Comment: It is a relative url I think, a local file located in the same folder if that's what you mean?